NO-CARRIER after adding 10G interface to bridge
Here's how I created the bridged interface and added the 10G interface to it:
sudo nmcli con add ifname kvbr0 type bridge con-name kvbr0
sudo nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname eno1np0 master kvbr0

Whenever we run the above config, I get NO-CARRIER:
ip a show dev eno1np0
4: eno1np0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1316 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp25s0f0np0

nmcli does not show the connections associated with the connections as active. I deleted associated connections, but the interface still shows NO-CARRIER:
$ sudo nmcli con del bridge-slave-eno1np0
Connection 'bridge-slave-eno1np0' (8f345987-bf8a-44d4-8727-74f8ce94241d) successfully deleted.
$ sudo nmcli con del kvbr0
Connection 'kvbr0' (0a17c157-2e12-4135-a942-ca3892266453) successfully deleted.

ethtool was showing Speed: Unknown! and Duplex: Unknown! (255) for the interface. I tried manually setting the speed and duplex using sudo ethtool -s eno1np0 speed 10000 duplex full, but the ethtool output is still the same.
The only way to recover is to log into the switch, remove the config for the associated port, and add the config back.

NO CARRIER means interface is not physically connected or can not otherwise complete L1 protocol handshake (e.g. speed mismatch, MDI/MDI-X mismatch, bad wrong optical connection, etc.). ethtool findings indirectly suggest the same: speed unknown because no speed was agreed with the peer. Check your cabling.

Our cabling is OK. Again, to recover from this problem before, we reloaded the port config on the switch and the port on the Linux host came up. This problem happens after adding the interface to bridge, so it doesn't make sense the cabling would be affected.


Which kernel driver is being used for the NIC? 2) Does the kernel driver log anything to dmesg after this? 3) Is the bridge interface brought up? 4) To rule out NM, does it still happen if you manually bridge it using ip link set eno1np0 master kvbr0?


@u1686_grawity in a normal Linux state of a bridge doesn't alter the state of its slaves in any way. This depends solely on the NIC (and the driver), and the driver doesn't care if it's a part of a bridge or has vlans or whatever.

@NikitaKipriyanov: It does – it enables IFF_PROMISC and IFF_ALLMULTI modes, for one, which both result in driver-specific operations to disable the hardware-level receive filtering. Most drivers do care if they have VLANs, too, with hardware-level filtering for those. And I think mlx5 for example also has specific support for bridge offload, although I'm not sure what that entails (I assume it's between ports of a multi-port NIC).

Well, I forgot about that. Still, these options don't (shouldn't, at least) influence carrier detection.

In theory they shouldn't, but from the interface being named eno1np0 (which seems to be RHEL-specific naming), I have suspicions of it being some kind of multi-port card with a driver that tries to do some kind of broken offloading for bridging.

I would rather think that if the action on the switch somewhat fixes it, the problem must also have been happening on the switch. Also, in any case, it would be quite interesting to see dmesg for both when the carrier is being lost and when it is recovered by flipping config on the switch.

This is happening because STP was enabled on the bridge. Once STP is enabled, the underlying interface starts sending BPDUs. Once the switch sees a BPDU, it shuts off the interface on its end.
To disable STP, I had to do both of these commands:
sudo nmcli con mod kvbr0 bridge.stp no
sudo brctl stp kvbr0 off


More precisely,  the link was deactivated by the switch because it had bpdu-guard enabled for an end-node port. A simple check of the switch log would have shown that right away.
